# Minimal surface with a "flat curve"

Tags: differential-geometry, elliptic-equations, minimal-surfaces

Let $\Sigma^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be a complete minimal surface and let's assume that there exists a smooth regular curve $\gamma \colon I \to \Sigma$ such that $K(\gamma(t)) = 0$  for all $t \in I$, where $K$ is the Gauss curvature of $\Sigma$.

Can I conclude that $\Sigma$ is flat, i.e. a plane?

Comment: Yes. Do you know how to interpret the Gauss map of a minimal surface as a holomorphic mapping to $\Bbb CP^1$?

Comment: Right, but then how do you conclude? Moreover, what about the higher dimensional version of my question? I.e. if $\Sigma^n \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is a minimal hypersurfaces such that its second fundamental form vanishes along a certain $\Gamma^{n-1} \subseteq \Sigma^n$, can I still conclude that $\Sigma$ is flat? In this case I can't use complex analysis argument, right?

Comment: I don't know about the higher-dimensional situation. But with regard to the first question: This is the identity principle for holomorphic functions — on a connected set, if a holomorphic function is zero on a set of points with a limit point, then it is identically zero.

Comment: Ah right!!! Thanks a lot!!